# Frobenius method in differentials equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, change-of-variable, frobenius-method

I'm having problems solving this exercise:

> Prove that, if $x(t)=t^\alpha y(t), \alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ satisfies:
> $$0=t^2x''(t)+tp(t)x'(t)+q(t)x(t) \quad \forall t \in (0,r) $$
> where $r>0$ is the radius of convergence of $y$ and $p$ and $q$ are analytic at $0,$ then $z(t)=(-t)^\alpha y(t)$ satisfies
> $$0=t^2z''(t)+tp(t)z'(t)+q(t)z(t) \quad \forall t \in (-r,0).$$

Any help? I assume that I must change my variable $t$ to $-t$ but I'm not sure how to solve the problem then.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933)